# Set default value of class property with @Bean configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I want to set a default LocalDateTime with a Lombok Builder for the following class. Its value should come from a @Bean configuration.

```
    @Data
    public class Foo {
        @Builder.Default
        LocalDateTime created = LocalDateTime.now(clock);
    }
```

Here the clock configuration. The value should be set when the object is initialized:

```
@Configuration
public class TimeConfig {
    public final static String TIME_ZONE = "UTC";

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE));
        return Clock.systemUTC();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to set a creation timestamp automatically with the current clock. The clock has a static value for tests.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use this clock configured instance in spring context and outside of it (in lombok)
then I will do it like this:
First create a singleton of Clock with configured time zone through static holder pattern

```
public class ClockInstance {
    public final static String TIME_ZONE = "UTC";
    static {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIME_ZONE));
    }

    public Clock getClock(){
        return Clock.systemUTC();
    }

    private ClockInstance() {
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static final ClockInstance INSTANCE = new ClockInstance();
    }

    public static ClockInstance getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Then use this clock instance in your spring configuration

```
@Configuration
public class TimeConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return ClockInstance.getInstance().getClock();
    }
}
```

And you will be able to use this correct configuration of clock in your Foo class

```
@Data
public class Foo {
    @Builder.Default
    LocalDateTime created = LocalDateTime.now(ClockInstance.getInstance().getClock());
}
```

This approach have some downsides, for example you cannot easly replace this clock instance for test to some fixed clock, so you will need to change `created` field in your tests, for example through a constructor of Foo class

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer :)